# Predicting from a gam (mgcv) with multiple "by" smooth terms

Tags: r, predict, gam, mgcv

I fitted a gam (mgcv) where y is modelled as a function of the time (t) by factor x1 and by factor x2 in separate smooth terms. I also included r, which should mimic a random factor.

```
library(mgcv)
dat <- data.frame(y = rnorm(1500,500,100),
                  t = rep(c(1:5),100),
                  x1 = as.factor(rep(letters[1:3],length.out=1500)),
                  x2 = as.factor(rep(LETTERS[1:5],length.out=1500)),
                  r = as.factor(rep(letters[4:26],length.out=1500)))


fit <- gam(y~s(t,by=x1,k=4)+s(x1,bs="re")+s(t,by=x2,k=4)+s(x2,bs="re")+s(r,bs="re"),data=dat,
           family="gaussian",method="REML")
```

I now wanted to predict y for a level of x1 across all levels of x2. However, a new level in x2 will lead to NAs in the prediction.

```
pred <- data.frame(predict(fit,type="response",newdata = data.frame(t=seq(0,5,0.1),
                                                                    x1="a",
                                                                    x2="new_level",
                                                                    r="new_level")
                           ,exclude = c("x2","r"),se.fit = T))

pred$fit
```

If I set x2 to one of the levels included in x2, it will predict values which will vary depending on the value/level I use even though I specified it to be excluded. Interestingly, the r takes new levels without leading to NAs. So, I figured this is connected to the "by" smooth terms. However, I could not come up with a solution.
One might be fitting tow models including only one of the smooth terms w
ith by, each? Would that be ok?

Comment: "Interestingly, the r takes new levels without leading to NAs." Yes, that's because random effects are (fundamentally) modelled as a (normal) distribution. If you have new level that was not in the training data, the expected value (mean) of that distribution is a decent prediction. You don't have the same for a categorical fixed effect. A distribution is not part of the model for these. It might still be (somewhat) sensible in specific cases to use mean effects for new levels, but it also might not be sensible. The model can't know that.

Comment: So, the question is: Why are you predicting for new levels (i.e., trying to extrapolate)? Do you have anything from your domain knowledge that can help with this extrapolation?

Comment: Acatually I do not need a new level but I want to get a prediction across all levels. Or somehow not taking the level x2 into account.  However, as I mention the prediction differs between the levels of x2. I am simply looking for an efficient method to plot a line based on the prediction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to specify `exclude` properly. For example,

```r
library("gratia")
library("mgcv")
su_eg4 <- data_sim("eg4", n = 400,  dist = "normal", scale = 2, seed = 1)
m <- gam(y ~ fac + s(x2, by = fac) + s(x0, by = fac),
         data = su_eg4, method = "REML")
```

This model has the following smooth terms

```
> smooths(m)
[1] "s(x2):fac1" "s(x2):fac2" "s(x2):fac3" "s(x0):fac1" "s(x0):fac2" "s(x0):fac3"
```

and hence if you want to exclude all the smooths containing `s(x0)` here, you need to use their full names. The factor `by` terms are named following this template: `s(<x>):<f><level>`, where

- `<x>` is the smooth covariate(s),
- `<f>` is the name of the factor
- `<level>` is the level of `<f>` that this smooth is for.

If you have lots of levels, it might get tedious to write all that out, so we can search for the relevant string

```r
sms <- smooths(m)
excl <- grepl("x0", sms)
```

and then adjust the `exclude` argument value accordingly

```
exclude = sms[excl]
```

as the `sms[excl]` evaluates to

```
> sms[excl]
[1] "s(x0):fac1" "s(x0):fac2" "s(x0):fac3"
```

In your case it seems you want to use

```
sms <- smooths(fit)
excl <- grepl("x2", sms) | grepl("s\\(r\\)", sms)
```

to capture the random intercept for `r` as well as any smooths that involve `x2`.

---

I actually think your model would be more simply specified using:

```
m <- <- gam(y ~
    s(t) + # "average" smooth of t
    s(t, x1, bs = "sz") + # smooth difference from `s(t)` for each level of x1
    s(t, x2, bs = "sz") + # smooth difference from `s(t)` for each level of x2
    s(r, bs = "re"), # random intercept term for `r`
  family = "gaussian", method = "REML")
```

Then you would just be able to use

```
exclude = c("s(t,x2)", "s(r)")
```

to exclude the smooths you want to exclude.

Note that with the `sz` basis, the group means are *included* in the basis, hence no parametric effects of `x1` or `x2` or their ranef equivalents are included in the model shown.